# How to get photos of a facebook album in iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am developing a iPhone application which get facebook album with this URL https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=2227470867|2.ZJr73vaEvFeN4fI_A70RFw__.3600.1297090800-100000566543036|WmgxdwULBgKXl8J7ksGIA1tyGik

Now i want to get photos from this album.

Any Idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So /me/albums returns an array of [Album objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/), each of which has an `id`.

If an album had an id of 99394368305, you can go to

https://graph.facebook.com/99394368305/photos

to get an array of [photo objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/).

Each of these will have the `picture` and `source` properties to get the image data from facebook.

They will all have an `images` array as well if you want pre-scaled images instead of just the originals.

---

All the facebook queries give JSON back - I'm assuming that you know how to parse this?

Comment: Can you please give answer for this question ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957260/how-to-comment-or-like-a-photo-in-facebook-through-fbconnect-or-graph-api-in-ipho

Comment: @deanWombourne https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos returns "False" when I execute it on my browser. How do you use it with FBConnect of Facebook iOS sdk?

Comment: What are you putting as your `album_id` and do you have permissions to view that album? (I'm assuming you're not just putting album_id straight in there!)

Comment: but in my case it is returning a blank json file am doing the same procedure as you suggested

Comment: @varunbhardwaj Ask a question yourself instead of commenting on someone else's question :) And when you ask the question, don't forget to put in the code you're using and the json you get back as a response.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 3):

It takes lot of time because of following steps;

1) get uid of friend using :

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@&fields=id,picture,name,birthday",fbGraph.accessToken];
```

2) put friends uid to get album id:

```
NSString *urlString1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/albums?access_token=%@",obj.uid,fbGraph.accessToken];

NSString *album = [[[_response1 objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"name"];

if ([album isEqualToString:@"Profile Pictures"]) 
{
      albumid = [[[_response1 objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:j]objectForKey:@"id"];
}
```

3) then put the album id to get the picture from that album:

```
NSString *albumUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/photos?type=album&access_token=%@",albumid,fbGraph.accessToken];

 NSString *picUrl=[[[[[_response2 objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"images"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"source"];
```

Kindly tell me some other method to get profile picture with large size in a single step to save time.

Comment: but i dont under stand that .. this all 3 method where i put.? i am newbie in ios. so plz guide me proper .

Answer (score 3):

The code below should do the right job for you. It gets albums for logged user and then requests for photos of this albums. In the place where is a comment you will have the access to all photos. For more info you can refer to [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album/photos):

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/albums"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary <FBGraphUser> *my, NSError *error) {
    if ([my[@"data"]count]) {
        for (FBGraphObject *obj in my[@"data"]) {
            FBRequest *r = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", obj[@"id"]]];
            [r startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *c, NSDictionary <FBGraphUser> *m, NSError *err) {
                //here you will get pictures for each album
            }];
        }
    }

}];
```

Comment: This is outdated/deprecated by Facebook developers, if you click on docs link. Hence I am adding new code by them below.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook developers new code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/{user-id}"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

[Latest Facebook Graph API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user)