# How to get my Facebook Profile Picture as button image

Tags: ios, facebook, uibutton

How can i get facebook profile picture and set it as button image. I have a button that will show facebook picture as its image. Help me out

Comment: Use the Social framework built in iOS. Write Objective-C code. Compile and run it.

Comment: geez @H2CO3, if you're going to give a snarky comment at least think a bit about what you're saying. [Social.framework is only for *composing* posts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html), one can't get profile pictures via it. And Ali could have found [the answer to his question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691075/ios-facebook-sdk-how-to-download-album-profile-photos-data) merely by doing a simple search.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann C'mon, this comment wasn't that bad. Definitely not as bad as OP was lazy.

Comment: Michael Dautermann issue resolved the given answer worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple stuff:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/1457691266/picture?type=square"]]; 
// Exchange 1457691266 with the ID of the user
yourProfilePicBtn.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Thankx Reno Jones it worked for me thankx alot