# How to retrieve photo album from Facebook in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve all my photo album from my Facebook account. I follow Graph API also and using latest Facebook API.

My code is like this:

```
 -(IBAction)getgallery:(id)sender
 {
   FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/albums"];
   [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary <FBGraphUser> *my, NSError *error) {
    if ([my[@"data"]count]) {
        for (FBGraphObject *obj in my[@"data"]) {
            FBRequest *r = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", obj[@"id"]]];
            [r startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *c, NSDictionary <FBGraphUser> *m, NSError *err) {
                //here you will get pictures for each album
            }];
          }
        }
    }];
 }
```

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921945/how-to-get-photos-of-a-facebook-album-in-iphone-sdk) link. But can't understanding properly. Please anyone can help me?

Nothing is happening when i press the *getgallery* button.

Comment: what is your json response?

Comment: Nothing will happens. When i click m not getting anything .

Comment: have you tried to print "m" on the console ? also have look at your permissions you given to facebook

Comment: I am unable to enter that loop. So how can i print. Please help me @Agent